# I can't run the command : python manage.py runserver

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-runserver

I can't run the command 'python manage.py reunserver' on my terminal. I dont know why, here is what the terminal shows me :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw4Ix.png)

Can please someone help me ?

I tried to execute the django dev server but it didn't worked. Normally, it show something like this : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABCdw.png)

Comment: Show us the INSTALLED_APPS section of your `settings.py` file.

Comment: Here it is : 


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "listings",
]

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: Okay, so `listings` is one of the installed apps.  Is this an app you wrote yourself, or is it a third-party app?

Comment: Yes, it is an app I wrote myself.

Comment: Can you share the directory structure of your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try again do new project with following commands:

```
python -m venv venv
venv\Scripts\Activate
pip -m install django
django-admin startporject NAME
```

Comment: your welcome, next time be careful and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You are not using virtual env. You need to activate your virtual env which you are using in your second image first then it will work flawlessly.

Comment: And how can I do this pease ?

Comment: To create a virtual env, run: `python -m venv venv` in the root of your project. Then, to activate the virtual env, run: `source venv/bin/activate` (for Linux/Mac) or  `venv\Scripts\activate.bat` (for Windows) at the root of your project.